# iPhone - Is .h file - the interface & .m file - the implementation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am quite new to iPhone dev (I am from C# background). As far as I understand - the .h file is considered as the Interface (header) & the .m file has got the corresponding implementation (method).

So it is mandatory that .m file should have all the implementation corresponding to .h file & vice-verse.

But when I try out I can declare some method in .h file without any implementation in .m & vice-verse. It is compiling & working correctly, without any errors. Why is this?

Please correct me if my concept is wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The .h file is the header file of the class it contains the function definitions, in c and c++ a function definition can exist without its body, however calling this function will cause an exception to be thrown

The .m file is the implementation, it contains the implementation of the functions you defined in the .h file,

Comment: Technically speaking the header file contains the "declarations" and the m file contains the "definitions"!  You can definitely define functionality in the header but this is usuall not done.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. But what about the case - when - there is an implementation (a method implementation) in .m file without any declaration in .h file?

Comment: yes it could work, but you would recive a warning that method is not found in the header file

Comment: @OmarAbdelhafith, it won't give warning in all cases.

Comment: @SebThomas, you can define your methods locally i.e. in the implementation if you don't intend to call those methods from outside the class. This will be just like the private methods of a class and I guess the same concept goes for almost all OO languages. You need to declare method signature in the interface, as the name suggest, if you are planning to call these methods outside the class.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is , because if you are declaring the function ...then it is not mandatory give the implementation of that function.That's why its give only the warning that your implementation is not complete.as .h is a declaration file and .m is the implementation file.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. But what about the case - when - there is an implementation (a method implementation) in .m file without any declaration in .h file?   Why it is not bringing an error?

Comment: it will also give you the warning .... its related to oops.. if we are concerning about the class, in the class it has only the function definition and data member.